# apply 2d mask to 1d array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 1d array and a 2d mask and would like to apply the 2d mask to the 1d array. By which I mean I want the indices where the array is true pluged into the 1d array giving me a n x 2 array where n is the number of trues in my array. E.g.

```
numbers = np.array([ 111, 2298, 5820, 6078, 7250])
mask = np.array([[False, False, False, False, False],
                 [ True, False, False, False, False],
                 [False, False, False, False, False],
                 [False, False, False, False, False],
                 [ True,  True, False, False, False]])
magic_function(arr=numbers, mask=mask)
```

Now since the first true has coordinates [1,0] I want the first result to be [2298, 111] and so on

```
array([[2298,111],[7250, 111],[2298,7250]])
```

Does this or something similar already exist in numpy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `numpy.argwhere` to create the array of indices needed for indexing:

```
numbers[np.argwhere(mask)]

#[[2298  111]
# [7250  111]
# [7250 2298]]
```

Comment: ah, yes `argwhere`. I was playing around with `np.take` and `np.where` but then you have to transpose it, `np.take(numbers, np.where(mask)).T`

Comment: Uhh that's cool and works. Thank you! But it seems we are creating an unnecessary array in the process. Can that be avoided?

Comment: Hmm, yes we are creating an index array, but notice it's sparse of its nature, so if mask has few Trues, then the array should be small. Also since you need both the row and column indices, I don't think you can avoid creating it. But feel free to wait and see if someone else has a solution

Answer (score 1):

A variation on the other answer  (`argwhere` is just `np.transpose(np.nonzero(mask))`):

```
In [26]: I,J=np.nonzero(mask)    
In [27]: I,J
Out[27]: (array([1, 4, 4]), array([0, 0, 1]))
In [29]: np.array([numbers[I],numbers[J]])
Out[29]: 
array([[2298, 7250, 7250],
       [ 111,  111, 2298]])
In [30]: np.stack([numbers[I],numbers[J]], axis=1)
Out[30]: 
array([[2298,  111],
       [7250,  111],
       [7250, 2298]])
```